# affine combination of more than 2 vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that affine combination of two vector in plane is the line which connect corresponding vectors
but what about affine combination of more that two vector ? \

Comment: In general, the affine span of a set of $n$ affinely-independent vectors is an $n-1$ dimensional hyperspace (which is to say, it's a translate of a $n-1$-dimensional subspace). Each of the "tips" of the vectors is in that span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a vector space, the affine span of $(n+1)$-affinely independent vectors is an $n$-dimensional affine subspace, i.e., a translate of an $n$-dimensional subspace.

**Some definitions**

A set of $n+1$ vectors $\{v_0,\dots,v_n\}$ is affinely independent if and only if the vetors $\{v_1-v_0,\dots,v_n-v_0\}$ are *linearly* independent.

An $n$-dimensional affine subspace of the vector space is a translate of an $n$-dimensional subspace. Thus, a space $A$ is an affine subspace if and only if $A-v$, for some $v\in A$, is a subspace of the vector space.

The affine span of a set of the $n+1$ vectors $\{v_0,\dots,v_n\}$ is all combinations of the form
$$
a_0v_0+a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n,
$$
where the $a_i$'s are members of the field of scalars over which the vector space is defined, and they satisfy
$$
a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_n=1.
$$

**Some examples**

1. Take two vectors $v$ and $w$ and consider all affine combinations
   $$
   u=av+bw = av+(1-a)w.
   $$
   This can be rewritten as
   $$
   u=a(v-w)+w,
   $$
   which means that this span consists of all vector $u$ on the line through $w$ in the direction $v-w$. For concreteness, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider
   $$
   v=(1,0,0),~~~~w=(0,1,0).
   $$
   Then the affine span consists of vectors of the form
   $$
   u=(a,1-a,0) = (a,-a,0)+(0,1,0) = a(1,-1,0)+(0,1,0),
   $$
   which we recognize as all points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ along the line through $(0,1,0)$ and parallel to $(1,-1,0)$.
2. Now consider the affine span of $v_0$, $v_1$, and $v_2$, consisting of all vectors of the form
   $$
   u=av_1+bv_2+(1-a-b)v_0 = a(v_1-v_0)+b(v_2-v_0)+v_0,
   $$
   which is now a "plane" through the point $v_0$ that is parallel to the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, *unless* $v_1-v_0$ and $v_2-v_0$ are parallel to each other, i.e., if they are linearly dependent.  Thus, we can see the importance of the $v_1-v_0$ and $v_2-v_0$ being *linearly* independent.  If they're not, then the affine span is again a line rather than a plane. For concreteness, consider the vectors
   $$
   v_0=(1,0,0),~~~~v_1=(0,1,0),~~~~v_2=(0,0,1).
   $$
   The affine span of this set of vectors is all vectors of the form
   $$
   u = (a,b,1-a-b) = a(1,0,-1) + b(0,1,-1) + (0,0,1),
   $$
   which spans a plane through $(0,0,1)$ parallel to the two vectors $(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$.

**Some proofs**

1. An affine span is a translate of a linear subspace.  Consider $\{v_0,\dots,v_n\}$ affinely independent. Then the affine span consists of all vectors of the form
   \begin{align}
   u &= (1-a_1-a_2-\cdots -a_n)v_0+a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+ a_nv_n\\
   u &= v_0+a_1(v_1-v_0)+a_2(v_2-v_0)+\cdots+ a_n(v_n-v_0).
   \end{align}
   We've already satisfied the constraint that the sum of the $a_i$'s is equal to 1, and except for $a_0$, the $a_i$'s can be any member of the field. Hence, the vectors
   $$
   a_1(v_1-v_0)+a_2(v_2-v_0)+\cdots+ a_n(v_n-v_0)
   $$
   span a *linear* subspace, and since affine independence of the original vectors implies linear independence of $v_1-v_0,\cdots,a_n(v_n-v_0)$, this subspace is of dimension $n$.  Finally, this subspace is translated by $v_0$.

**Some intuition**

Having built up the definitions, examples, and proofs, I *think* it should now be clear how to think about affine spans. Affine spans are just translates of $n$-dimensional vector subspaces, so, to the extent that you can think of your vector space is being the same as $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can think of the affine spans as lines, planes, etc., i.e. spaces that look like translates of $\mathbb{R}^m$ when embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For instance, if you have three non-colinear points in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then these three vectors are affinely independent, and their affine span is the unique plane passing through these three points, which is a translate of a planar (two-dimensional) subspace (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: thanks for your explanation, with your help, I can understand the affine combination better.